# Ansible - Convert found file's mtime to YYYY-MM-DD format

Tags: ansible

I'm Using Ansible to find, compress and rename log files, and would like to rename the compressed logs with their timestamp (mtime) appended to their name, like so:

`log.log` ---> `log-2021-07-06.log`.

Ansible lets me extract the mtime in the following format:

`log.log` ---> `log-1575048603.1364305.log`

Im finding the logs using the `find` module:

```
 - name: Locate Logs
    find:
      paths: /some/path
      file_type: file
      recurse: yes
      patterns: '*some-log-pattern.log*'
      age_stamp: mtime
    register: found_logs
```

And showing Ansible's found mtime like so:

```
- name: Show found mtime
    debug:
      msg: "Will rename {{ item.path | basename }}.gz to {{item.path | basename}}-{{ item.mtime }}.gz"
    with_items: "{{ found_logs.files }}"
```

Which gives me the format mentioned above.

Is there a way to convert Ansible's format to standard `YYYY-MM-DD` format, as shown above?

I've come across many similar questions, as well as the Ansible Docs (https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#handling-dates-and-times), but have been unsuccesful thus far.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Q: *"**Find and rename (compressed) log files.**"*

A: Use the filter *strftime*. See [Handling dates and times](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#handling-dates-and-times). For example, given the compressed files

```yaml
shell> ls -1 some/path/
logA.log.gz
logB.log.gz
```

the tasks

```yaml
    - name: Locate Logs
      find:
        paths: some/path
        file_type: file
        recurse: yes
        patterns: 'log*'
        age_stamp: mtime
      register: found_logs

    - name: Show found mtime
      debug:
        msg: "Rename
              {{ item.path }} to
              {{ _arr.0 }}.{{ _arr.1 }}-{{ _date }}.{{ _arr.2 }}"
      loop: "{{ found_logs.files }}"
      loop_control:
        label: "{{ item.path }}"
      vars:
        _arr: "{{ item.path.split('.') }}"
        _name: "{{ _arr.0 }}"
        _ext1: "{{ _arr.1 }}"
        _ext2: "{{ _arr.2 }}"
        _date: "{{ '%Y-%m-%d'|strftime(item.mtime) }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  msg: Rename some/path/logB.log.gz to some/path/logB.log-2021-07-06.gz
  msg: Rename some/path/logA.log.gz to some/path/logA.log-2021-07-06.gz
```

Comment: Your example helped me tremendously. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction!